# how to find iso-cost contours on a 2d plot efficiently

Tags: plotting, geometry

Consider a 2D plot in which dimension 1 and 2 represent quantity 1 and 2 respectively ranging over 0 to 100. Each point in the space corresponding to (x,y) represent cost of choosing quantity 1 as x and quantity 2 as y. Assume cost increases monotonically with increase in quantities. I want to find iso-cost lines(contours) in the space. Say all those points whose cost is equal to some K. How do I find it efficiently without checking cost of all the points in the space which is 100 cross 100.?

Comment: Are you after a *Mathematica* solution or would this question be better off at math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: See [ContourPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ContourPlot.html) in the docs.

Answer (score 5):

```
Manipulate[Row[{
  Plot3D[2 x +3y + 3  x^2 +4 y^2 +5 x y,{x,0,100},{y,0,100},
     BoxRatios->1,ImageSize->400,
     MeshFunctions->{#3&},Mesh->{{k}},MeshStyle->Directive[{Thick,Red}]],
  ContourPlot[2 x +3y + 3  x^2 +4 y^2 +5 x y==k,{x,0,100},{y,0,100},
    ContourStyle->Directive[{Thick,Red}],ImageSize->400,
    PlotLabel->Style["k = "<>ToString[k],20]]}],{{k,30000},0,100000}]
```

[image]